# Fail to connect to camera service cause null

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio

Using **Twilio** , when receiving call always front camera fail to load.

Note : It works fine when calling.

**Error Message :**  Unable to open camera Camera 1, Facing front, Orientation 270:Fail to connect to camera service cause null

**Code**

```
  cameraCapturer= CameraCapturerFactory.createCameraCapturer(this, CameraCapturer.CameraSource.CAMERA_SOURCE_FRONT_CAMERA, capturerErrorListener())

/*
```

* CameraCapture error listener
  */

```
 public CapturerErrorListener capturerErrorListener() {
    return new CapturerErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(CapturerException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Camera capturer error: " + e.getMessage()+" cause  "+e.getCause());

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you use old twilio lib. Current version is 0.12.1

Comment: used version  is 0.11.0

Comment: Have you solved this error?

Comment: 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'   still  error is there

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Using twillio  0.12.2 version.